# Why can't my program access the math methods in Java?

Tags: java, class, math

I'm learning Java for the first time. I wrote a simple program:

```
public class Solver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double angle = 1.5;
        double height = Math.sin(angle);
        System.out.print("The sine of " + angle + " is: ");
        System.out.println(height);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to compile this, I get the following error in the terminal:

```
Solver.java:4: cannot access Math
bad class file: ./Math.java
file does not contain class Math
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
        double height = Math.sin(angle);
                    ^
1 error
```

Why can't I access the Math class?

Comment: What's the name of the class - I assume Solver.java?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If a file is called Math.java (which it seems to be), it *must* contain a class called `Math`. Take a look at [this post](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2011/01/javas-file-names-and-class-names.html). Java is looking for a file called `./Math.java`, which doesn't contain seem to contain a class called `Math` in your case.

If you're actually trying to use the standard Java `Math` package, you need to either get rid of anything named `Math.java` in your project directory, since that will conflict with the built-in one, or else use a fully-qualified import to access the standard one: `import java.lang.Math;`. Imports from the `java.lang` package are not usually necessary, but if you have a conflicting name, it's important to use a fully-qualified import to access it explicitly.

Really, it's best to just get in the habit of [putting everything in a named package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) and using fully-qualified imports all the time anyway. You'll save yourself a lot of hassle.

Comment: `Solver.java:4: cannot access Math` seems to indicate that the file name is Solver.java

Comment: @ChrisForrence Yes, but his problem appears to be in Math.java: `bad class file: ./Math.java file does not contain class Math`

Comment: Ah, so _this_ filename is Solver.java, but there exists another file name in this directory with the name Math.java. Cool. Removed downvote, added vote.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I started out with a file called Math.java, but then realized that wouldn't work. I made a new one, but left the old one in my directory. I didn't realize the compiler would accept it without it being a .class file.

Comment: @RaidenWorley Glad to help. For clarity on your other point, compiling is the process that *produces* `.class` files from `.java` (source) files.

Answer (score 15):

Delete the file `Math.java` that you have probably inadvertently left in your source code directory. This file is preventing the normal usage of JDK's `java.lang.Math` class.

You should also note that defining classes in the default package is bad practice and will cause various issues for you along the way. Put your source code into a named package.

Comment: +1 - Bang on correct; upvoted just for "Put your source code into a named package"